# How can I show the parallax effect for images appearing after some rows in Android RecyclerView similar to google calendar android app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, parallax

I want to show parallax effect to the images appearing in recycler view after some rows similar to this google calendar app

[image: I want to show parallax effect to the images appearing in recycler view after some rows similar to this google calendar app]

Comment: could you create something similar?